# Convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Verify the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1 \right)$$

What I test is:

1)Succession: $a_n=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1$ is always positive for $n>0$.

2. Verify the Cauchy criterion for $a_n$.
3. Test an decreasing through derivative: Derivative of $a_n:\frac{-1}{2n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$.

So since an is monotone decreasing for n>0 then an is convergent.

I also verified absolute convergence of an with root test with $0$ as result so  an is convergent. Am I right?

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: Why WolframAlpha tell me the series is divergent? @eyeballfrog

Comment: Probably an input error. [It says it converges for me.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5En+%28Sqrt%5B1%2B1%2Fn%5D-1%29%2C+%7Bn%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D)

Comment: It is semi-convergent but not absolutely convergent. Multiply by conjugate and $\sqrt{1+1/n}+1<3$ so $|a_n|>1/3n$.

Comment: Oh thx, it was an input error!